# Assessing overfitting via learning curves

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, overfitting

I have intended to find overfitting or underfitting cases. I have used MLP classifier and Logistic regression of scikit-learn. How do I know which is a good fit? Or Which one underfitting or overfitting? I appreciate your time. Thanks!

[image: Fig 1 using MLP]

[image: Fig 2 Using logistic regression]

Comment: the numbers for training and validation are too close to each other; I don’t see a strong signal for both underfit and overfit.

Comment: @gunes Can I say that my models were trained well and fitted well?

Comment: That’s tough to say because accuracy is not the best option to evaluate the performance. Look at our metrics also, and if you see similar train/test perf, it’s good to go.

Comment: @gunes Here is my results: Model with selective features F1 score:  0.859313449634215
5-fold cross-validation score on selected features for training  data: 0.9832591998546073

Comment: @gunes Also 5-fold cross-validation score on selected features for test data: 0.9808457571811621

Answer (score 0):

I would say the first plot is better than the second plot. The first plot signifies the training score is decreasing and the test score is increasing which is a sign of proper fit. You could probably improve the fit by hyperparameter tuning or feature selection/engineering or adding some "good data".

The second plot, training score is decreasing and test score is not increasing which is a sign of a badly fit model. Probably underfitting I guess.